The sequence $0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 10, 52, 459, 1271, 10094, 63133,...$
Let $a_0$ be a permutation on $\{1, 2, ...,N\}$ (i.e. $a_0 \in S_N$) . For $n \geq 0$:
If $a_n(i+1) \geq a_n(i)$, then $a_{n+1}(i) = a_n(i+1) - a_n(i)$.
Otherwise, $a_{n+1}(i) = a_n(i+1) + a_n(i)$.
$a_{n}(i)$ is defined for $0<i≤N-n$.
My question is this: For a given $N$, how many $a_0 \in S_N$ satisfies $a_{N-1}(1) = 0$? (Can anybody provide an exact expression? If not, can anybody provide an approximation at least?)
An example of such permutation for $N=5$ is $(1, 4, 5, 2, 3)$
$$(1, 4, 5, 2, 3) \rightarrow (3, 1, 7, 1) \rightarrow (4, 6, 8) \rightarrow (2, 2) \rightarrow (0)$$
I calculated the number if such permutations by bruteforce for $1\leq N\leq11$:
$0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 10, 52, 459, 1271, 10094, 63133$
I see no pattern, and the sequence doesn't appear anywhere on the OEIS.

Wondering: does this algorithm ever terminate prior to $a_{N-1}$ ?

@CarlWitthoft It does for the identity permutation for $N≥4$. The smallest $N$ where there's a non-trivial permutation that satisfies that condition is $N=7$ and here's one example: $3, 4, 1, 7, 2, 5, 6$
